# Angular PWA not working offline on safari and old browser

Tags: angular, manifest, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I created my PWA following this:
https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started

It works perfectly offline on my Chrome Desktop, but it does not work offiline on iOS 12 Safari or Android 5 Chrome.
I am accessing network with ip XXX.XXX.XXX:8080 from an localhost ssl server using http-server command.

I dont understand. I need to configure the manifest manually for old browsers and safari where service workers dont work? Or my Angular PWA project generated in CLI should does everything for me?

example my code
https://github.com/GuilhermeLessa/teste-pwa

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie still can't stop myself typing in here, please correct me everyone! The max safari supports (as documented) is 50Mib (and that 50Mb is for both indexedDB and Cache Api) on mobile devices but on the desktop it says unlimited, i never had a chance to verify it. I developed an application using Express, Nodejs and some obvious JS. It works fine with Chrome, Firefox and Opera (on android devices), MS Edge 38 version doesn't seem to support it. Safari supports in a way that when offline, it loads the page, texts and images but not the videos which I assume is the reason on the 50Mib limit, as I only tried on the mobile device. MS Edge version 42 supports almost fully (atleast on my ASUS p027) didn't get a machine with the latest MS Edge intalled. Please also note that not all the old browser will support whether you mention it in the manifest or not as they are not compatible with service worker or Cache API. I know making an app PWA one of the steps is to have manifest file, but PWA on the other hand does work without manifest file only the score of lighthouse would be lesser than 100%. So, in precise I would say old browsers don't support PWA and you will remain in trouble. Also, Chrome and Opera browsers can have storage pool of up-to 33% of available free disk space and each origin may have up-to 20% from that pool. Firefox pool is 50% of the available free disk space but the origin may have maximum of 2048, and this is called hard limit (upper bound can be lesser than this depending on the pool). Also, the browsers excercise LRU (Least Recently Used) policy also known as best effort on temporary storage while it doesn't apply on persistent storage. for chrome high site engagement, or making a site book marked (while the book marks are less than 5), adding a site to the home screen or allowing push notification, if any of these 4 option taken chrome will turn it into persistent storage so the LRU won't take place on it. Where as in Firefox, you have to explicitly code it and the browser ask using a pop-up if the user is happy for the persistent storage or not. I know I have diverted but it all comes under PWA. Hope you will get better answer. Cheers:)

Comment: But dont even work on Chrome on Android 5. My question is this: Even generating an officially Angular PWA Project CLI "ng add @angular/pwa --project *project-name*". Do I need to manually create the manifest?

Comment: I've tried before to create the manifest and it did not work on Safari iOS 12, nor Chrome on Android 5. But I'll try again.

Comment: I have no experience of Android 5 to be honest. I have a ASUS tab having android 7, Moto Android 8. For them I can assure you they support chrome, opera and Firefox as well as MS Edge (42 version). I just googled Android 5 release data, I am sure Android 5 wouldn't support PWA. Like you said it works fine on your Desktop, on which OS and what version of Chrome you are using. Please bear in mind chrome, opera, FF and MS Edge all support it but from certain versions and then onward. I would say when old versions don't support PWA is there any use of adding them in the manifest? Don't think so!

Comment: Old browser dont support Service Workers, but support Manifest API Cache. Is not it the right thing to do?

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using on Android 5, and what device you are using Android 5? To run a PWA you have to register Service worker! Does it say in the console if Service worker registered? If yes, then you need to look into your code, it can be as little error as a not closing a tag or could be complicated. You can debug it in the browser. Cache API and IndexedDB are interfaces of service workers, if your browser/operating system don't support SW then what's the point of them having in the manifest. Chrome supports maximum PWA, if your app is running on chrome, you need it's serious.

Comment: No, Service Workers and Application Cache are distinct technologies. Service Workers are evolution alternative to Application Cache. Old browsers dont recongnize Service Workers. I think implements SW for modern browsers, and Application Cache through Manifest to old browsers. IndexedDB works on Android 4.4. Service Workers just work on Android 6.

Comment: Thanks. I am coming with this argument. We might be on the different pages though! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API plz check the link.

Comment: just try you application with the same browser version on Android 7 or 8. Also, a bit nosy but what browser version are you using on Android 5? and on what device? If it runs on Android 7 or 8 then there should be a problem with the manifest file, although I don't agree you can run your pwa on older versions of browsers an OS only mentioning them in the manifest file. I haven't seen any clue on this issue, gone through the manifest files but!